# CMap - What will happen if we add more elements to the map than the hashtable size?

Tags: c++, mfc, hashmap, msdn

AFAIK, The `CMap::InitHashTable` method should be called before any element is added to the map. In other words, the hashtable size cannot be changed after the first element is added to the CMap object.

Also from MSDN, `To minimize collisions, the size should be roughly 20 percent larger than the largest anticipated data set`.

So my question is, what happens if I create a CMap object with default hashtable size (i.e. 17) and then add (e.g.) about 40 elements to it? We are assuming here that no two keys will generate similar hash.

Comment: As a more modular tool, you can use `std::unordered_map` . You can define your own hash function designed for your particular needs in this structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overfilling a hash table results in collisions. The items that collide get put in a list, which must be searched. Everything still works, it just gets a bit slower. If your hash table is properly-sized and your hash function is decent, then inserts and lookups in your hash table will be constant-time. In your overfull hash table, these times will increase due to having to walk the lists that result from collisions.

Comment: So there is nothing like auto increment of the hashtable? Somthing like std::vector (or simillar) do when we add more elements than the initial capacity. They just grow.

Comment: I don't know about the CMap implementation, but there are certainly implementations of hash map/table that will automatically grow. The one gotcha here is that growing a hash map requires that you re-insert all of the existing entries into the new (grown) backing store, so it can lead to unexpected performance profile. In other words, inserting a new entry is very fast except for once in a while when it is 4-5 orders of magnitude slower (depending on the number of entries already there).